# Prove or give counter example: $G \cong N \times G/N \Rightarrow N$ has a normal complement.

Tags: group-theory, exact-sequence, quotient-group, direct-product, retraction

My original question is the following:

Given a short exact sequence $1 \to N \xrightarrow{\iota} G \xrightarrow{\pi} Q \to 1$, we have:
\begin{equation*}
    G \cong N \times Q \ \Longrightarrow \ \text{the sequence is a left split sequence}
\end{equation*}

The converse is very easy to prove, but I couldn't prove this direction. Also, when I researched this problem (e.g. see theorem 3.2 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/splittinggp.pdf)), I saw that if we put some restrictions to the isomorphism between $G$ and $N \times Q$, then we can deduce that the sequence is left split. So I think that my statement is wrong in this form.

To find a counter-example, first, I tried to minimize the variables in the statement. It is not hard to see that the above problem is equivalent to the following:

Given any group $G$ and normal subgroup $N$, we have:
\begin{equation*}
    G \cong N \times G/N \ \Longrightarrow \ N \ \ \text{has a normal complement}
\end{equation*}

I looked at a lot of groups, but I couldn't find any counter-example. It would be great if you could give one, or you could give a hint about how to prove it if it is not incorrect.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You said "short exact sequences", so $1\rightarrow N \rightarrow G\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 1$. I suppose, the next question (later) is then also about solvability. What did you solve related to short exact sequences? You said "I was solving a problem related to short exact sequences"...

Comment: @DietrichBurde Actually, the full problem is this: Given a short exact sequence $1 \to N \to G \to Q \to 1$, we have $G \cong N \times Q$ iff the sequence is a left split sequence.

Comment: Yes, this is true, because kernels are normal subgroups.

Comment: If $G=N \times Q$, then $N=\{(n,0)\}$ in $G=\{(n,q)\}$, and we find a map back from $G$ to $N$ such that the composition is the identity.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But $G$ and $N \times Q$ are not equal, they are only isomorphic.

Comment: The thing here is that, intuitively, $G$ and $N \times Q$ can be isomorphic "by coincidence".

Comment: Very correct does not exist.

Comment: @BobDobbs So, are you saying that this implication is actually correct? If this is so, how can I prove it because I really cannot see how?

Comment: @MetinErsinArıcan I'am topologist. I am still reading group theory to solve this. It takes time. At least 2 months.

Comment: We can take an isomorphic copy so that $G=N\times Q$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But how? I mean, we just have an isomorphism $\phi : G \to N \times Q$. You may identify $N$ with $\iota(N)$ and $Q$ with $G/\iota(N)$ for simplicity, but you cannot identify $G$ with $N \times Q$. A priori, there is no relation whatsoever between $\phi$ and $\iota, \pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a counterexample, let $G$ be the (restricted) direct product of countably
many copies of $C_2 \times C_4$: i.e. $$G= {\large \times}_{i>0} (\langle x_1 \rangle { \times} \langle y_i\rangle ),$$
where $x_i$ and $y_i$ have order $2$ and $4$, respectively. Now let $N = \langle x_{2i}, y_1^2 \mid i>0 \rangle$.

Then $G/N \cong G$ and $G \cong N \times G/N$, but $N$ has no normal complement in $G$.

Comment: Ah, very nice. Thank you. Actually, even $N=\langle y_1^2 \rangle$ works right? Because it is easy to see that $G \cong N \times G/N$, and moreover, any subgroup $M$ with $MN=G$ must contain $y_1$ and hence $N$, so $N$ has no normal complement.

Comment: Yes that's right - I was being unnecessarily complicated!